# A surprising solution to the cube integral of $\sqrt{1+x+y+z}$

Tags: definite-integrals, pi

I calculated the cube integral over
$[0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,1]$.

The solution is quite close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
is it just a coincidence?
is there an intuition for why it is?

Comment: The exact value (found using Mathematica) is $\frac{8}{105}\left( 127 + 24\sqrt{2} - 81\sqrt{3} \right) \approx 1.573$

Comment: No so close. They differ by $0.14$% ... but it is amazing.